# Issues returning a Request result in Batman.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, batman.js

I'm having issues returning a result from a Batman.Request call. I've comment the area where I'm calling the return. I'm pretty sure I can't just call return there, but I can't seem to find any documentation that will point me in the right direction.

Model:

```
class Web.Inbox extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'inbox'

  @persist Web.InboxStorage

  @encodeTimestamps()

  @classAccessor 'task_entries', ->
    request = new Batman.Request
      url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/inbox'
      autosend: false
      success: (response) ->
        results = new Batman.Set
        results.add(Web.TaskEntry.createMultipleFromJSON(response))
        console.log(results) # The value I want is here!
        return results # I assume the issue is here
    request.send()
```

Controller:

```
class Web.InboxController extends Web.ApplicationController
  routingKey: 'inbox'

  index: (params) ->
    task_entries =  Web.Inbox.get('task_entries')
    @set('task_entries', task_entries)
    console.log(task_entries) # not the same value as I attempt to return 
                              # in the request
```

Console log from the model (What I want):

```
Set {_storage: Array[1], length: 1, _batman: _Batman, constructor: function, isCollectionEventEmitter: true…}
_batman: _Batman
_storage: Array[1]
0: Array[15]
0: TaskEntry
1: TaskEntry
2: TaskEntry
3: TaskEntry
4: TaskEntry
5: TaskEntry
6: TaskEntry
7: TaskEntry
8: TaskEntry
9: TaskEntry
10: TaskEntry
11: TaskEntry
12: TaskEntry
13: TaskEntry
14: TaskEntry
```

Console log from the Controller:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you saw bradstewart's response in IRC, just in case, here it is again:

```
Web.Inbox.get('task_entries')
```

This accessor fires an AJAX request, but it's asynchronous. It doesn't return the value you're looking for because that value is still being loaded from the server. As Brad pointed out, the accessor returns the `Batman.Request` object, not the value from the server.

What you could do is make the accessor return a `Batman.Set`, then also use the accessor to fire a `Batman.Request` which will load records into that Set. When the set is updated, your view will be updated too. For example:

```
  @classAccessor 'task_entries', ->
      @_entries = new Batman.Set
       new Batman.Request
        url: "/inbox"
        method: "GET"
        success: (data) =>
          records = Web.TaskEntry.createMultipleFromJSON(data)
          @_entries.add(records...) # if you're on master branch, you could use `@_entries.addArray(records)`
      return @_entries
```

This will cause the accessor to return a Set, which is empty at first, but the Set will be populated by the `Batman.Request` and your view will be updated.

(oops, cross-posted from [gist](https://gist.github.com/tylerkern/fb914cae4110cc09d255))

Comment: I missed that response. Thanks for posting it here!